# How to make a 100% height container in Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here's what I am trying to achieve.

[image]

My HTML currently looks like:

```
<body>
 <header>
 ... // BS sticky navbar - always visible no matter what
 </header>
 <main>
   <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
     </div>
   </div>
 </main>
 <footer>
   .. // Footer at bottom but content can push it down
 </footer>
```

Either `.container` or `.row` can be the white div. It needs to touch the footer when there is not enough content.

The `main` div must stay 100% width.

The solution must be CSS only and work in IE10+/modern browsers. IE9 would be great but not necessary as long as the alternative doesn't look like crap (i.e. the footer in the middle of the text).

I have tried so many solutions such as:

```
- http://thatemil.com/blog/2013/11/03/sticky-footers-flexbox-and-ie10/
- http://www.fredonism.com/archive/min-height-100-percent-and-sticky-footer.aspx
```

Unfortunately nothing I found works. Most of the solutions I see do not involve the inner white div and only use the `main` one. The 2nd solution linked above, for example, shrinks the `main` div to be the white are which doesn't work in my case. Things like `100vh` don't seem to work well when the content is larger - I end up with the footer in the middle of the page on scroll.

Comment: Is it fixed height for the header and footer?

Comment: Yes - both are fixed height - say 50px;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browser support: IE9+/modern browsers.

**JSFiddle** - http://jsfiddle.net/z1ts4rro/

```css
html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}
body {
    background: lightgoldenrodyellow;
    margin: 50px 0;
}
header, footer {
    background: lightseagreen;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
}
header {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
footer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
.container {
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: white;
    min-height: calc(100vh - 100px);
}
```

```html
<header>header</header>
<main>
    <div class="container">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec porttitor, augue a vehicula pretium, arcu lorem interdum ligula, sed vehicula purus turpis et velit. Praesent rhoncus venenatis malesuada. Proin sem felis, vulputate eu tincidunt ac, dictum nec tellus. Aliquam a ex bibendum, porttitor ipsum id, varius leo. Aliquam ornare suscipit justo vel rhoncus. Integer sit amet risus nec lectus fermentum egestas. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas nisl neque, aliquam in tincidunt vel, vehicula suscipit neque. Quisque faucibus gravida lectus. Ut porttitor tincidunt elementum. Sed urna erat, pellentesque sit amet commodo vestibulum, eleifend ac diam.</div>
</main>
<footer>footer</footer>
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to address my issue. Where's the inner white container with margins on the side?

Comment: Please. Perhaps I am missing the obvious.

Comment: Nope. This is the issue that the 2nd link I posted has. I need the `main` to be 100% width as in my figure.

Comment: @Yashua I posted another update, it seems to be all working as expected.

Comment: You da man!  I couldn't get it working in my code because I use LESS which likes to butcher the `calc` line.  So for the LESS users this needs to be ` min-height: calc(~"100vh - 100px");`.

Comment: Best answer ever.

Answer (score 0):

Well I was able to trick things into something agreeable. I'll post it here in case that works for someone else. The trick was to use the `main:after` property set to absolute positioning with the same color as the container div.

Note that I am using BS header so it is ommitted from the code. Just use the standard BS sticky nav.

```
html {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}


main {
   position: relative;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  background: red;

  &:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    width: 1170px;
    display: block;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -585px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: white;
  }
  .container {
    z-index: 1000;
    background-color: white;
    position: relative;
   .row {
      position: relative;      
    }
  }
}

footer {
  z-index: 1000;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #000; 
}
```